# Laravel reuse form with variable that exists sometimes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a form which contains separate `date` and `time` fields, when submitted my controller actually joins the two values to store into my `datetime` field in my database.

Form:

```
<div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('date')) has-error @endif">
    {!! Form::label('date', 'Date') !!}
    {!! Form::date('date', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('date') }}</small>
</div>

<div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('time')) has-error @endif">
    {!! Form::label('time', 'Time') !!}
    {!! Form::time('time', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('time') }}</small>
</div>
```

This works fine when creating a new record, but I want to reuse the form on my edit pages (using the same partial), I have to edit the values in the inputs like so:

```
<div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('date')) has-error @endif">
    {!! Form::label('date', 'Date') !!}
    {!! Form::date('date', $booking->reservation_datetime->format('Y-m-d'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('date') }}</small>
</div>

<div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('time')) has-error @endif">
    {!! Form::label('time', 'Time') !!}
    {!! Form::time('time', $booking->reservation_datetime->format('G:i'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('time') }}</small>
</div>
```

But this will consequently will cause issues on the create page.
How can I use the same form but only load values on edit pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an intermediary variable:

```
<?php $date = isset($booking->reservation_datetime) ? $booking->reservation_datetime->format('Y-m-d') : null ?>
<div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('date')) has-error @endif">
    {!! Form::label('date', 'Date') !!}
    {!! Form::date('date', $date, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('date') }}</small>
</div>

<?php $time = isset($booking->reservation_datetime) ? $booking->reservation_datetime->format('G:i') : null ?>    
<div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('time')) has-error @endif">
    {!! Form::label('time', 'Time') !!}
    {!! Form::time('time', $time, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('time') }}</small>
</div>
```

Comment: Would it be best practise to set the variable inside the controller or inside the blade template?

Comment: IMO, best practice limits logic within templates.  The presence of a `<?php` inside a template is a smell -- it works, but it could be better.  The logic could go into a controller, a form factory, a route: all depending upon what the template connects to.